# Is it valid returning locally allocated memory - not local variables

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* address(void);

int main(void)
{
    printf("The address is: %p", address());
    return 0;
}

char* address(void)
{
    char* temp = malloc(20);

    return temp;
}
```

The compiler doesn't give any kind of error, and up to what I've read, I've not come across such an example if it is either valid or not a recommended approach.(given that the memory freeing up is done at some point). Is it ok to return the address of locally allocated memory?

Comment: Something to think about: What does `malloc` itself do? But you should `free` allocated memory.

Comment: @Olaf, allocates a memory block(at my starters understanding), but, confused if it's similar to automatic variables.

Comment: That was not my point. Read my comment carefully and thing about it! Then read the documentation of `malloc` and the standard about dynamic memory allocation. You ask for basics fo the C language you can find in any C book; please do some research on your own before asking such questions. So: what have you found out? What **specifically** is unclear? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on your usage, **as long as you keep track of the calls to address()** and you free the memory at that address when you don't need it anymore, it should be fine.

check out this [link](https://blog.feabhas.com/2010/09/scope-and-lifetime-of-variables-in-c/) (not mine - under the "Dynamic Objects" title)

Comment: that hits the jackpot!!, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are nicely paranoid about returning things from functions, keep that up.
You worry that returning a pointer to malloced memory is as bad as returning a pointer to a local non-static variable. I will assume that you are aware of the need to free that memory before you drop the last pointer to it. It does get freed at program termination, but you do not want to rely on that, because it represents a thinking trap. If you do not have a clear idea/plan, when to free anything you ever malloced, then you are heading towards evilly hard to debug memory leaks. They only hurt if you leak in a fast and/or big loop.

While the local variable stops existing when the function is left (i.e. linker is not aware of it anymore and the memory will soon be used for different things) things are different for malloced memory.
The function "malloc()" is API for dynamic memory. It finds a space for you in the heap (assuming there is still room). It will keep that piece of memory reserved for you until you stop wanting it and say so by using "free()".
In order to do that, "malloc()/free()" access additional administrative data. That allows "free()" to know the size of your memory, even though free does not get the size parameter "malloc()" got. The same data also allows "malloc()" to know how much space is available and where; quite complicated.

The difference between heap and stack is the kind of accessing. Stack is used from the top. A few bytes used for local variables. The elegance of stack is its efficiency, it just knows where the stack top is; much less complex than what "malloc()/free()" have.
The drawback is you have to stop using the space before anything beneath your piece can be used again. That is what kills local variables.

So, as long as you say "free()" at some point, you are safe.

Comment: 'need to free that memory at some point before program termination' - what need?  Can you name one environment where that is necessary?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit fair point. I had to think what I really meant. When I found a way to phrase it I put that into the answer. Thanks.